# Python: how to run Cron job on the cloud when your script requires a local directory?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I have this Python script which uses Selenium to open Chrome and "do stuff". I wish to run this program as a Cron job but have a couple of problems/Inquiries:

Im having trouble choosing a service to run the Cron job on as Selenium requires that I give it a local directory path on my computer for Chrome Driver to open Chrome. If I want to run this Cron job on the cloud, which service would be best fitted for this, or what is a workaround for this. I have heard about "installing Python on the server side" but not sure as to what that means exactly

Comment: It doesn't actually require local path, but path to chromedriver is required. Just include chromedriver file into your project and run it directly from your test/script.

Comment: but in order include chromedriver in my project, wouldnt it need to access my local directories at some point? dont quite understand what you mean

Comment: what do you mean by local directories? no it would not need to include it. Use something like `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to find the path of your project in cloud